# Reshaping data set in reshape package

Tags: r, reshape

I am trying to reshape my data using Reshape package. I struggle to reshape it. I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Data are as follows:

```
structure(list(ID = 1:3, group = 1:3, v1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), v2 = c(1L, 1L, 0L), v1.1 = 1:3, v2.1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), v1.2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L ), v2.2 = c(0L, 1L, 1L), v1.3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), v2.3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("ID", "group", "v1", "v2", "v1.1", "v2.1", "v1.2", "v2.2", "v1.3", "v2.3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

ID  group      X1              X2              X3          X4   
ID  group   v1  v2  v1  v2  v1  v2  v1  v2
1   1       1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1
2   2   1   1   2   1   0   1   1   1
3   3   1   0   3   1   1   1   1   1
```

I want to have data like this. Many thanks for your help

```
ID  group   X   v1  v2
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   2   1   1
1   1   3   1   0
1   1   4   1   1
2   2   1   1   1
2   2   2   2   1
2   2   3   0   1
2   2   4   1   1
3   3   1   1   0
3   3   2   3   1
3   3   3   1   1
3   3   4   1   1
```

Comment: Sorry, please ignore "ID" "group" at the top table. The top one is extra. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work.

```
df     <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, group = 1:3, v1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), v2 = c(1L, 1L, 0L), v1.1 = 1:3, v2.1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), v1.2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L ), v2.2 = c(0L, 1L, 1L), v1.3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), v2.3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("ID", "group", "v1", "v2", "v1.1", "v2.1", "v1.2", "v2.2", "v1.3", "v2.3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
result <- reshape(df,idvar=1:2,
                  varying=list(c(3,5,7,9),c(4,6,8,10)),
                  timevar="X",
                  direction="long")
result <- with(result,result[order(ID,group,X),])
result

#       ID group X v1 v2
# 1.1.1  1     1 1  1  1
# 1.1.2  1     1 2  1  1
# 1.1.3  1     1 3  1  0
# 1.1.4  1     1 4  1  1
# 2.2.1  2     2 1  1  1
# 2.2.2  2     2 2  2  1
# 2.2.3  2     2 3  0  1
# 2.2.4  2     2 4  1  1
# 3.3.1  3     3 1  1  0
# 3.3.2  3     3 2  3  1
# 3.3.3  3     3 3  1  1
# 3.3.4  3     3 4  1  1
```

Normally, I'd recommend `melt(...)` in the `reshape2` package, but with more than one set of "value" columns (`v1` and `v2`) this might be quicker.

Comment: Many Thanks, jlhoward,  May I have codes in reshape2

Comment: Post the result of `dput(df)` in your question.

Comment: structure(list(ID = 1:3, group = 1:3, v1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), v2 = c(1L, 
1L, 0L), v1.1 = 1:3, v2.1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), v1.2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L
), v2.2 = c(0L, 1L, 1L), v1.3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), v2.3 = c(1L, 1L, 
1L)), .Names = c("ID", "group", "v1", "v2", "v1.1", "v2.1", "v1.2", 
"v2.2", "v1.3", "v2.3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

Comment: The code does work. It produces the same result as in your question.

Comment: +1. This seems to work for me. Not sure where the OP is stumbling.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `merged.stack` from my "splitstackshape" package, which you could apply like this:

```
library(splitstackshape)
merged.stack(
  df, var.stubs = c("v1", "v2"), 
  sep = "var.stubs")[, .time_1 := NULL][, ind := sequence(.N), 
                                        by = c("ID", "group")][]
#     ID group v1 v2 ind
#  1:  1     1  1  1   1
#  2:  1     1  1  1   2
#  3:  1     1  1  0   3
#  4:  1     1  1  1   4
#  5:  2     2  1  1   1
#  6:  2     2  2  1   2
#  7:  2     2  0  1   3
#  8:  2     2  1  1   4
#  9:  3     3  1  0   1
# 10:  3     3  3  1   2
# 11:  3     3  1  1   3
# 12:  3     3  1  1   4
```

---

Alternatively, in the same package, there's `Reshape`, which is a wrapper that attempts to simplify the use of base R's `reshape()`. It would be slower than `merged.stack` in the long run though.

To use it, first rename the columns named "v1" and "v2" to "v1.0" and "v2.0":

```
setnames(df, c("v1", "v2"), c("v1.0", "v2.0"))
Reshape(df, var.stubs = c("v1", "v2"), sep = ".")
#     ID group time v1 v2
#  1:  1     1    1  1  1
#  2:  2     2    1  1  1
#  3:  3     3    1  1  0
#  4:  1     1    2  1  1
#  5:  2     2    2  2  1
#  6:  3     3    2  3  1
#  7:  1     1    3  1  0
#  8:  2     2    3  0  1
#  9:  3     3    3  1  1
# 10:  1     1    4  1  1
# 11:  2     2    4  1  1
# 12:  3     3    4  1  1
```

---

Another alternative (since you seem to be insisting on a "reshape2" solution) is to first `melt` the data, then do some modifications to the data to get it ready for `dcast`.

Here's the approach (starting with the original "`df`" data, not the one where we've renamed the columns above):

```
library(reshape2)
## melt the data
dfL <- melt(df, id.vars = c("ID", "group"))
## replace "v1" and "v2" with "v1.0" and "v2.0"
dfL$variable <- gsub("(v1$|v2$)", "\\1.0", dfL$variable)
## split that column into two parts and bind back with the original df
dfL <- cbind(dfL, colsplit(dfL$variable, "\\.", c("var", "time")))
## reshape from long to wide
dcast(dfL, ID + group + time ~ var, value.var = "value")
#    ID group time v1 v2
# 1   1     1    0  1  1
# 2   1     1    1  1  1
# 3   1     1    2  1  0
# 4   1     1    3  1  1
# 5   2     2    0  1  1
# 6   2     2    1  2  1
# 7   2     2    2  0  1
# 8   2     2    3  1  1
# 9   3     3    0  1  0
# 10  3     3    1  3  1
# 11  3     3    2  1  1
# 12  3     3    3  1  1
```

You'll have to increment the "time" column if you want exactly the same output that you show in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
nddf = data.frame(ID=numeric(), group=numeric(), x=numeric(), v1=numeric(), v2=numeric())
for(i in 1:nrow(ddf)){
    nddf[nrow(nddf)+1,]=c(ddf[i,'ID'], ddf[i,'group'], 1, ddf[i,3], ddf[i,4])
    nddf[nrow(nddf)+1,]=c(ddf[i,'ID'], ddf[i,'group'], 2, ddf[i,5], ddf[i,6])
    nddf[nrow(nddf)+1,]=c(ddf[i,'ID'], ddf[i,'group'], 3, ddf[i,7], ddf[i,8])
    nddf[nrow(nddf)+1,]=c(ddf[i,'ID'], ddf[i,'group'], 4, ddf[i,9], ddf[i,10])
}
nddf
   ID group x v1 v2
1   1     1 1  1  1
2   1     1 2  1  1
3   1     1 3  1  0
4   1     1 4  1  1
5   2     2 1  1  1
6   2     2 2  2  1
7   2     2 3  0  1
8   2     2 4  1  1
9   3     3 1  1  0
10  3     3 2  3  1
11  3     3 3  1  1
12  3     3 4  1  1
```